# wrong assets loaded rendering application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a kind of strange problem with assets. 
In *application.html.erb* trying to include controller specific assets this way

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller] %>
```

*application.js* looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require leaflet
//= require select2
//= require_tree ./general
//= require turbolinks
```

`General` folder contains some common JS files. Application uses 2 controllers: `Index` and `Profiles` (root route is "index#index"). At some moment Rails starts to load assets in wrong way: on index page `profiles.js` are loaded and `index.js` on /profiles/new. This problem only appears when I press `index` or `create profile` links in navbar. No problems seems to be opening this pages in separated tabs or just reloading page using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. So I assume that it's some turbolinks problem?

Comment: open your browser console and have a look at the response that comes from the server. what javascript does it link to? is everything wired correctly?

Comment: @phoet Thank you for response. Yes, response contains correct links to assets, but firebug "scripts" contains wrong one (this is correct for turbolinks?).

Comment: i have no idea. i would never even think about using turbolinks...

Comment: jep, that also my decision...